# Set a variable based upon the result of a command

Tags: batch-file

I want to copy a self made string to the clipboard using a [batch-file](/questions/tagged/batch-file).

My try...

```
set X=git log --pretty=format:"%h %ai" -n <commit>
set Y="and something else"

set "XY=%x% some other characters %Y%"
echo %XY%| clip
```

...failed :(

My big problem is, that I have no idea how this could be done.

```
set X=git log --pretty=format:"%h %ai" -n <commit>
```

Output should be

```
27fdvvd <Date> some other characters and something else
```

---

**SOLUTION:**
Finally, I got that to work:

```
set BRANCHNAME=great_branch
for /f "tokens=* USEBACKQ" %%a in (`git log --pretty^=format:"%%h %%ai" -1 <commitSHA>`) do (SET COMMIT_INFO=%%a)
ECHO %COMMIT_INFO% on %BRANCHNAME% | clip
```

Output/Clipboard content:

```
<shortSHA> 2019-08-22 15:26:30 +0200 on great_branch
```

Thanks to all for their patience :)

Comment: Open a Command Prompt window and read the output when entering `for /?`.

Comment: @schipfl
Please tell me the anwer to my question about how this could work`
```
set COMMIT_INFO="${git log --pretty=format:"%%h %%ai" -1 ceb9fab47c683e44f3bca09d03889d20025ad554}"
```

Comment: "_...failed :(_" is not a problem description. What happened? Why was that wrong?

Comment: @KodJunk, please formulate an answer using the duplicates clearly listed at the top of the question, _which is now closed_!

Comment: @underscore_d the command has not been executed.